# Only apply Bootstrap CSS to certain children components

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, docusaurus

I have several components of Website A (e.g., a customized form) built in Bootstrap. I have Website B build in Docusaurus. Now, I would like to copy these components to Website B. As Bootstrap and Docusaurus have conflict in general. I'm thinking if it is possible to limit the css of Bootstrap to certain components.

For instance, initially, I have a form in a page `myForm.mdx.md` in Website B:

```
---
id: 'MyForm'
title: 'MyForm'
sidebar_label: 'MyForm'
---
import MyForm from '../src/components/MyForm';

Page containing MyForm
    
<MyForm>
</MyForm>
```

I tried to add `<Head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" ... ... /></Head>` to the component of Website A to build `src/components/MyForm/index.jsx` of Website B:

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { successMessage: null }
  }
  componentDidMount() {}

  submit(e) {
    this.setState({ successMessage: true })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <Head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      </Head>
        <div className="container--fluid container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
              <form
                method="post"
                action="https://www.mywebsite.com/download"
                onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}
              >
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-6 pt-3">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="First name*"
                        name="firstname"
                        required
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-lg-6 pt-3">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Last name*"
                        name="lastname"
                        required
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-12 pt-3">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      {this.state.successMessage ? (
                        <div className="alert alert--success">
                          Thanks for downloading
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        <button
                          type="submit"
                          className="btn  btnGreen form-control"
                          style={{background : "var(--ifm-color-primary-darker)" , border:"1px solid var(--ifm-color-primary-darker)" , color: "#fff"}}
                        >
                          Download
                        </button>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default MyForm
```

The display of Website B shows that the form does have the Bootstrap style. However, we can see the conflicts in other parts (or children components) of website B: sidebar, navigations, etc.

So does anyone know if it is possible to only apply the css of Bootstrap to the component `MyForm`?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to override any "problems" caused by Bootstrap with CSS applied AFTER bootstrap.css.